# float and integer comparison in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, precision

I am aware of the technical limitations when comparing floats, but consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1.12060000],
                   'col2': [1.12065000]})
df
Out[155]: 
        col1       col2
0 1.12060000 1.12065000
```

As you can see `col2` and `col1` are exactly `0.00005` apart. Now, I want to test that. I understand that this returns the wrong result because I am using decimals

```
(df.col2 - df.col1) < 0.00005
Out[156]: 
0    True
dtype: bool
```

However, more puzzling to me are the following results

```
(100000*df.col2 - 100000*df.col1) < 5
Out[157]: 
0    True
dtype: bool
```

while

```
(1000000*df.col2 - 1000000*df.col1) < 50
Out[158]: 
0    False
dtype: bool
```

Why does the comparison to 5 fails and only the last one works? I thought using integers would solve the issues when comparing floats?

Thanks!

Comment: My **guess** is this is the result of floating point precision. [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455612/7758804)

Comment: floating point precision I guess...

Comment: yes, but the usual "cure" has always been to convert to integers (here by multiplying by 10000). There has to be a fool-proof way to proceed... I hope

Comment: Problem is, you lose association with the present of floating point precision. That is `(1000000*a - 1000000*b) != 1000000*(a-b)`.

Comment: thanks @QuangHoang, could you please explain in more details the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point precision is the issue here. These numbers seem natural in base-10 but your computer stores them in base-2 which leads to weird things such as [`0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004`](https://0.30000000000000004.com/). In your example:

```
>>> 1.12060000*100000, 1.12065000*100000
(112060.0, 112064.99999999999)
>>> 1.12060000*1000000, 1.12065000*1000000
(1120600.0, 1120650.0)
```

This is how the first difference is less than 5 (it's 4.99999999999)

> yes, but the usual "cure" has always been to convert to integers (here by multiplying by 10000).

Ah! But you're **not** converting to integers! Just to larger floats! The "cure" here is to call `round(float)` or in the case of a DataFrame, [`df.round()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html):

```
>>> round(1.12060000*100000), round(1.12065000*100000)
(112060, 112065)
```

Comment: really interesting. thanks! oddily enough, using `int()` did not work. perhaps `round` is the only way

Comment: `int()` always rounds down, so `112064.99999999999` becomes `112064`!